# VsCode (Ctrl + K + D) - JSX element has no correspondig closing tag

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

When I press `ctrl + K + D` to format my javascript file which contains react code, the formatting gets destroyed.

Typescript complains about the formatting, nevertheless the code runs fine.

> JSX element has no correspondig closing tag

Is there an extension available which formats the react file with `.js` extension correctly?

[image]

Comment: [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) might be a nice alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) but to make it work properly you need to use `.jsx` extension for files with jsx.

Sometimes it conflicts with beautify so to make it work without adding `.jsx` you may need to add this to your vs-code config.

```
"beautify.ignore": [
   "**/*.js",
   "**/*.jsx"
]
```

Comment: my first steps with reactjs :D

Comment: I read that the use of `.jsx` is not recommended ([thread](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3052)). Is there a way to format it adequately without using `jsx` extension?

Comment: I found out that it may not work properly because of conflicts with beautify https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/454 But updating your config should help with it.